# How do I make tcpdump not print the tcp headers?

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I tried this:

```
tcpdump -s 1500 -A -l -i eth0 '(port 6667) and (length > 74)'
```

I need only the ascii part of it. How do I remove the rest?

Comment: with tshark you can do it with:  tshark -l -i eth0 -f 'port 6667 and greater 74' -T field -e data

Comment: It says 28 packets captured but doesn't print anything to STDOUT.

Comment: Do you mean ASCII7?

Answer (score 20):

As Josh suggests, tcpflow can print just the TCP packet data to a file or STDOUT. You can pipe tcpdump to tcpflow like this:

```
tcpdump -i lo -l -w - port 23 | tcpflow -C -r -
```

To only view one side of the conversation, you can use filters for tcpdump, e.g. `dst port 23`.

Comment: Why would you need to start `tcpflow` as root?

Answer (score 17):

I feel the most elegant solution is just to ditch tcpdump. No pipes of any kind:

```
tcpflow -c port 6667
```

And that's it.

Comment: You saved my life, I want to buy you a cookie

Comment: And you can use `-D` to print the data in hex, in case your traffic isn't textual.

Comment: Want to show all TCP trafic from/to a specific IP in hex format? `tcpflow -Dc host xx.xx.xx.x`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the exact syntax for `tcpdump`... in fact, I have marked this question as a favorite because I would like to know! But as an alternative solution, you could try using [`tcpflow`](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/) instead. It works essentially the same way, but it prints ASCII output much better; it excluded the headers and prints packets sequentially as a flow, so it's easier to read and follow at times than `tcpdump`.

Answer (score 5):

A quick and dirty way to do this is to filter the output through strings:

```
tcpdump -nli eth0 '(port 6667) and (length > 74)' -s 0 -w - | strings
```

Sometimes you don't have other tools and for a quick peek into the payload this is enough. It's no good if you need the exact payload for injection or an exact analysis, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the ASCII part you can use: `tcpdump -s 1500 -A -l -i eth0 '(port 6667) and (length > 74)'|sed 's/\.//g'` or with ngrep: `ngrep -d eth0 -lq . '(port 6667) and (length > 74)' |sed -rn '/^  /s/\.//gp'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last week - I used the wireshark gui instead and did a "copy readable ascii" for the interesting packets.

I was (successfully) trying to pin down a problem with a http request to a web-service and its XML-answer.