# Display delta timestamp and UDP data payload with tcpdump/tshark

Tags: tcpdump, tshark

I have a 1.5Gb capture of small UDP packets that I would like to turn into a CSV with just timestamp and UDP payload data in hex format.

An example of the desired output would be as follows:

```
% head Data3.txt 
0.000000,0000000041000000005ec812ac00047dce00000000
0.000194,0000000042000000005ec812ac00047db500000000
0.000227,0000000041000000005ec812ac00047dce00000000
0.000619,0000000042000000005ec812ac00047db500000000
0.000663,0000000041000000005ec812ac00047dce00000000
0.000854,0000000042000000005ec812ac00047db500000000
0.000883,0000000041000000005ec812ac00047dce00000000
```

I do not need this exact format, just a format that can later be transformed into this data (in this case they are 21 bytes length UDP packets).

I am struggling to achieve this with tcpdump without success, so I have found that tshark can do the job:

```
  tshark -r May31Jun5.pcap -t r -T fields -e frame.time -e data
```

That command gives the delta time and payload as required (see below excerpt).

```
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567001000 CEST    0000000041000000005ed4297300049fe300000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567014000 CEST    0000000042000000005ed4297300049fb100000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567028000 CEST    0000000041000000005ed4297300049fe300000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567042000 CEST    0000000042000000005ed4297300049fb100000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567056000 CEST    0000000041000000005ed4297300049fe300000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567066000 CEST    0000000042000000005ed4297300049fb100000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567106000 CEST    0000000054000000005ed4297300049fb100000001
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567124000 CEST    0000000041000000005ed4297300049fe300000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567137000 CEST    0000000042000000005ed4297300049fb100000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:27.567152000 CEST    0000000041000000005ed4297300049fe300000000
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:28.095487000 CEST    0000000041000000005ed4297300049fe300000000
```

However I would like to have just seconds with decimals, so instead of:

```
Jun  1, 2020 00:02:28.095487000
```

It would be:

```
148.095487000
```

How can I achieve that? I guess it is possible because the GUI version of Wireshark display that value.

Comment: Does this help?: [How do I make tcpdump not print the tcp headers?](https://serverfault.com/q/206734/274176)

Comment: I have tried to pipe the content of the pcap tcpdump captured file into tcpflow `tcpdump -r May31Jun5.pcap -l -w - | tcpflow -C -r -` but it gives nothing. Reading tcpflow man page I suspect it only works for TCP, could that be the case?

Comment: I learnt  here (https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/38818/see-udp-data-with-tshark) that `tshark -r dns.cap -T fields -e data` gives the payload. Now I just need to add the delta timestamp. Any tip for that is welcomed. (I did not know Wireshark has a command line utility)

Comment: I have edited the question including the last findings. Now I just need to format the delta timestamp into a pure seconds elapsed since beginning value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a CSV-style output for simple fields, you can use the `-T fields` option with `tshark`, combined with the `-E separator=,` option to use commas as separator as opposed to tabs.

Next, to figure out what kind of field names to use, check the status bar in the GUI for a selected field, or use `tshark -T pdml -r some.pcap` for example, or `tshark -G fields` for a full list of supported fields.

For columns, you can use the special `_ws.col.<name>` field. For example, `_ws.col.Time`.

Combining this information, you can use something like:

```
tshark -r your.pcap -Tfields -Eseparator=, -eframe.time_relative -edata > your.csv
```

Bonus information:

- If a UDP (e.g. DNS) consumes the UDP payload, the `data` field will be empty. Add the `--disable-protocol dns` to avoid that.
- In the current development version, a new `udp.payload` option has been added which should avoid the previous option. (commit [v3.3.0rc0-250-gf04475167a](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=commit;h=f04475167a36f8c8cfb98e91375403b544a13513))
- If for some reason a field occurs multiple times, it will be output, separated by commas. You can use the `-E occurence=1` option to limit the results to the first value only.
- For more details about these options, see the [tshark manual page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

Comment: Thanks, excellent and very complete answer and it includes tips I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
This is so far what I have done. I can either get one field or another, but not both.

To get timestamp delta:

```
tshark -r May31Jun5.pcap -o 'gui.column.format:"Time","%t"' > May31Jun5.time.csv
...
262.625098
262.625148
262.625237
262.625762
262.625781
262.625800
262.626037
262.626050
262.626206
262.626232
262.626455
262.626679
...
```

To get data payload:

```
tshark -r May31Jun5.pcap -Tfields -e data > May31Jun5.data.csv
...
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
0000000042000000005ed428ff0004a02e00000000
0000000054000000005ed428ff0004a02e00000002
0000000054000000005ed428ff0004a01500000002
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
0000000042000000005ed428ff00049ffc00000000
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
0000000042000000005ed428ff0004a01500000000
0000000054000000005ed428ff0004a01500000001
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
0000000042000000005ed428ff0004a01500000000
0000000054000000005ed428ff0004a01500000001
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
0000000042000000005ed428ff00049ffc00000000
0000000054000000005ed428ff0004a04700000002
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
0000000042000000005ed428ff00049ffc00000000
0000000041000000005ed428ff0004a04700000000
...
```

Then in UNIX you can easily mix both with `paste`:

```
paste -d',' May31Jun5.time.csv May31Jun5.data.csv | sed 's/^ *//g' > May31Jun5.csv
```

How to geth both a the same time with `tshark`? No Idea.